# Google Maps Infowindow Sharing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am currently building a google map that pulls in lat/lng co-ordinates from 3 different categories of a custom post type in wordpress. Im building this as i learn but struggling to get past an issue of sharing a single infowindow.

Here is the code.

```
(function() {
window.onload = function() {

// Creating an object literal containing the properties // we want to pass to the map
var options = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.789397,-2.255003), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// Creating the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

var commercialplaces = [];
var commercialmyTitle = [];
var commercialmyContent = [];

var housingplaces = [];
var housingmyTitle = [];
var housingmyContent = [];

var riversideplaces = [];
var riversidemyTitle = [];
var riversidemyContent = [];

// Adding a marker to the map
<?php 
          query_posts( array( 
            'post_type' => 'livesites',
            'livesites-cat'=> 'commercial',
            'showposts' => 1000,
            'order' => ASC,
            'orderby' => title,
            ));

          if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();        
?> 

commercialmyTitle.push('<?php the_title(); ?>');
commercialmyContent.push('<?php the_field('address'); ?>');
commercialplaces.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php the_field('location_for_map'); ?>));

<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?> 

// Looping through the commercialplaces array
for (var i = 0; i < commercialplaces.length; i++) {

// Adding the marker as usual
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: commercialplaces[i],
map: map,
title: commercialmyTitle[i],
icon: 'http://icansee.co.uk/commerciallivesite.png',
});


// Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
// that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
(function(i, marker) {
// Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
// i and marker as they were during its creation
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: commercialmyContent[i],
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(i, marker);

}

// Adding a marker to the map
<?php 
          query_posts( array( 
            'post_type' => 'livesites',
            'livesites-cat'=> 'housing',
            'showposts' => 1000,
            'order' => ASC,
            'orderby' => title,
            ));

          if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();        
?> 

housingmyTitle.push('<?php the_title(); ?>');
housingmyContent.push('<?php the_field('address'); ?>');
housingplaces.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php the_field('location_for_map'); ?>));

<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?> 

// Looping through the commercialplaces array
for (var i = 0; i < housingplaces.length; i++) {

// Adding the marker as usual
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: housingplaces[i],
map: map,
title: housingmyTitle[i],
icon: 'http://icansee.co.uk/housinglivesite.png',
});
// Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
// that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
(function(i, marker) {
// Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
// i and marker as they were during its creation
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: housingmyContent[i],
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(i, marker);

}

// Adding a marker to the map
<?php 
          query_posts( array( 
            'post_type' => 'livesites',
            'livesites-cat'=> 'riverside-interiors',
            'showposts' => 1000,
            'order' => ASC,
            'orderby' => title,
            ));

          if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();        
?> 

riversidemyTitle.push('<?php the_title(); ?>');
riversidemyContent.push('<?php the_field('address'); ?>');
riversideplaces.push(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php the_field('location_for_map'); ?>));

<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?> 

// Looping through the commercialplaces array
for (var i = 0; i < riversideplaces.length; i++) {

// Adding the marker as usual
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: riversideplaces[i],
map: map,
title: riversidemyTitle[i],
icon: 'http://icansee.co.uk/interiorlivesite.png',
});
// Wrapping the event listener inside an anonymous function
// that we immediately invoke and passes the variable i to.
(function(i, marker) {
// Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
// i and marker as they were during its creation
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: riversidemyContent[i],
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(i, marker);

}
}
})();
```

Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: "Sharing single infowindow"... could you elaborate?

Comment: I have read that v3 of the api now handles infowindows differently, what i have is an individual instance of the infowindow for each marker meaning that they can all be open at the same time. I have read that each marker can share a single instance of an infowindow and adjust the content accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the single infoWindow-instance somewhere:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

inside the click-handler for the marker only set the content for this infoWindow and open it:

```
(function(i, marker) {
// Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of
// i and marker as they were during its creation
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
infowindow.setContent(riversidemyContent[i]);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(i, marker);
```

Comment: Magic that worked a trick, thanks Dr.Molle